# Weird behavior by the dynamically created input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

i am trying to create input text fields dynamically. Using jquery i am able to generate input fields, but whenever the user tries to click on any of the dynamically created fields, his pointer automatically moves to the first field. Now By using TAB key only he is able to navigate to a particular field and enter details.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g84t4/1/) is the fiddle to experience what i am facing.

And here is the code

HTML

```
<head>    
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <label><div id= "div1"><input  class="address" id="friend1" type="text"></div></label>    
<div id='wrapper2'><div id="button2" class='removebutton'>Remove</div><div id="button">Add!</div></div>        
<div id="submit-button" >GO!</div>
    </body>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
          var friends_cnt = 1;

    $('#wrapper2').on('click','#button',function ()   
                        {                 
                            clicknum = 0;
                            if (friends_cnt < 11) 
                            {
                              $('<div  id = div'+(friends_cnt+1)+'><input type="text" class="address"  id="friend' + (friends_cnt+1) + '"></div>').insertAfter('#div'+friends_cnt);        
                              $(function() {
                               $("#friend"+(friends_cnt+1)).autocomplete({
                                  source: function(request, response) {
                                    geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
                                      response($.map(results, function(item) {
                                        return {
                                          label:  item.formatted_address,
                                          value: item.formatted_address,
                                          latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
                                          longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
                                        }
                                      }));
                                    })
                                  },
                                });
                              });    
                             friends_cnt++;
                          }
                          else 
                          {

                          }

                        });



                        $('#button2').click(function()  
                        {                      
                           clicknum = 0;
                           if(friends_cnt > 1)
                            {
                               $('#friend'+friends_cnt).remove();
                               $('#div'+friends_cnt).remove();
                               friends_cnt--;
                            }     

                        });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is html issue. I have moved a `label` close tag like this:

```
  <div id= "div1"><label></label><input  class="address" id="friend1" type="text" /></div>
```

and now the pointer is not jumping , look:

http://jsfiddle.net/g84t4/4/

Comment: can u explain me what happened ? How label causes this  ?

Comment: @user1263375 here what i found on w2schools: *The `<label>` element does not render as anything special for the user. However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because if the user clicks on the text within the `<label>` element, it toggles the control.* In your case "the control" was always the first `input`!